# Google Cloud TTS synthesizeLongAudio parent format

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I try to use the TTS [synthesizeLongAudio](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations/synthesizeLongAudio) method.

From documentation, **parent** param should be in the form of

```
projects/*/locations/*
```

But I alwasy get this error:

> Google\ApiCore\ValidationException: Could not map bindings for google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechLongAudioSynthesize/SynthesizeLongAudio to any Uri template. Bindings: Array ( [parent] => projects/XXX/locations/global ) UriTemplates: Array ( [0] => /v1/{parent=projects/*/*locations/*/*voices/*}:SynthesizeLongAudio )

So required form seems to be:

```
projects/*/locations/*/voices/*
```

But I never read about this **voices** param in any documentation or example.

Does anyone know what this param refers to?

I tried to use a TTS voice name as "fr-FR-Standard-A", with no success...

Thank you !